# OpenGL warning from a .NET program

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, opengl, virtualbox

What is the likely cause of this warning?

```
OpenGL Warning: crPixelCopy3D: simply crMemcpy'ing from srcPtr to dstPtr
```

This is from a C# application previously known to work on `Windows 7` built with `Visual Studio 2008` and `MySQL` and displays a simple XAML dialog for the desktop (not browser).  This project has been rebuilt (compiled) on `Windows 8 (in Ubuntu 12.04 and VirtualBox 4.3.2 with 2D and 3D acceleration enabled)` and built with `Visual C# 2010`.  As far as I can recall, this application has nothing to do with graphics so this warning is surprising.  The application simply reads `XML` files and plugs the data in to `MySQL` tables and displays a simple dialog when finished.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn off VirtualBox's 3D acceleration and the problem no longer appears.  Simple XAML dialogs are not going to benefit much from so-called "3D" effects so there's not going to be a noticeable benefit.

This same solution will also get rid of the following error which occurs when the application exits.

```
err:[0xc784]:d3d_surface:D:\tinderbox\add-4.3\src\VBox\Additions\WINNT\Graphics\Wine_new\wined3d\surface.c 6245: Surface 000000001CCDFB30 does not have any tp to date location.
```